# Is this the right behavior to expect from the new Express 4 Router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have recently started a new app with Express 4.0, and I really liked the new `express.Router()` thing.

Something that got me stuck for quite some time was the following behavior:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    router = express.Router();

router.get('/me', function(req, res, next) {
    if(someBoolean) {
        return next(); //here I expect to get a 404 error from express!
    }

    res.json({name: 'yourName'});
});

router.get('/:user_id', function() {
    //any code here!
});

app.use('/users', router);
```

I always used `next()` (in Express 3.x) to either call the next middleware or to force a `404` from the server.

Since `/users/me` and `/users/45` are totally different routes and are not mounted in a way that one should come after another, I wonder why I get code in `/users/:user_id` evaluated after calling `next()` in `/users/me`.

Am I doing something wrong or things are supposed to work different in Express 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected. In Express 4 all middleware/routes are executed in the order that they are added to your app, so the path for your second `router.get()` is tested and matches because `:user_id` could be any kind of token, numeric or otherwise (basically any character that isn't `/`).

You can fix this at least in a couple of different ways:

1. Don't call `next()` in your first `router.get()`
2. Use a RegExp instead of a string to ensure that `user_id` only matches a numeric value. For example: `router.get(/^\/(\d+)$/, function() {`. However then you have to access the param via regexp group index instead of by a name: `var user_id = req.params[0]`.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to detour the execution flow straight to the last middleware in the chain, so I can centralize all of my `404` errors in a single place?

Comment: There's no public API to do that that I'm aware of. You could do something like `var err = new Error(); err.status = 404; next(err);` or directly return a 404 with `res.send(404);`.